# Arduino microphone/AMB decoder combination gets interrupted

Tags: c, arduino, decoder

## Microphone readout gets randomly interrupted

I have a microphone hooked up to my Arduino on a Serial hardware port 2.
https://sigrok.org/wiki/Colead_SL-5868P

I receive data from the microphone by sending 0x20 to it. The following functions read out it's data.

FlushMic1 is a function to flush out the Serial2 buffer, so we can read out the correct data from the buffer.

```
String getMic1()
{
  String valueMic;
  
  if(flushedMic1())
  {
    Serial2.write(0x20);

    while (Serial2.available() <= 10){;}
    valueMic = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      int data = Serial2.read();
      valueMic += String(data);
    }
  } 
  return valueMic;
}

bool flushedMic1()
{
  bool returnBool = false;
  while(Serial2.available())
  {
    Serial2.read();
    returnBool = true;
  }
  return returnBool;
}
```

On another port I have a transponder loop connected, to measure passing transponders.

If a transponder passes it sends char to the Serial Hardware port 1. It can be detected if it includes a '@'.

```
bool isTransponderPassing()
{
  char data = Serial1.read();

  if (data == '@')
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Running the getMic1() function in a loop works perfectly fine. If the : if(isTransponderPassing())  is used in the in main loop I sometimes get the correct data, sometimes false data, when I receive false data, the entire program gets interrupted, which propably fills the buffer with 16's and that's why we receive 16's.

Who knows where my program can get stuck?

```
void setup()
{
  // Starts the serial monitor
  Serial.begin(2400);

  // Starts Serial monitor of AMB decoder
  Serial1.begin(9600);

  // Starts Serial monitor of microphone 1
  Serial2.begin(2400);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println(Serial2.available());
  Serial.println(Serial1.available()); 
  
  if(isTransponderPassing())
  {
    Serial.println(getMic1());  
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd advise you to pick a tool chain that comes with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, because I wasn't aware Serial.readString() in getMic1() has a delay of 1 second. So I should just read the documentation better next time.

So everyone, Serial.readString() has a delay of 1 second, hope this saves time for others!

Use Serial.readStringUntil(char ofChoice) instead, this reads the buffer into a String, but quits when it has reached the given char.

```
Buffer = "Hello world";

// Serial.readString() does:
delay(1000);
return Buffer;

result : "Hello world"

// Serial.readStringUntil("o") does:
return BufferUntilChar("o")

result : "Hello wo"
```